# Best Practise for Multiple Store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, stores, websites

Anyone suggest in which way Website/Store/StoreView can be used for this.

- Need to have 10 domain like store1.domain.com, store2.domain.com... .
- A product in Store1 can be visible in all other stores or in only one
  store.
- A product in Store1 can be in different price in each store.
- A product availability will be different in each store Each
- Store(store1, store2..) must support multiple language.
- While searching in store1.domain.com it must never display the product which is hidden in that domain.

So for this is it possible to have Store1 in Magento as Store or Website ? To accomplish this how to use the Website/Store/StoreView classification.

Answer (score 1):

You should split your stores into different websites with multiple stores views beneath each website, one for each language.  You can add products to specific websites and also make them enabled/disabled at a website level.  You can also set product prices at the website level (`system->config->catalog->price`).

Bear in that (logically) you can only manage product stock at a global level, so if you need a different stock level for the same product between different stores you will have to create products specific to each store that need this.

Comment: So is it not advisable to have one website with multiple store and multiple store-view?

Comment: The reason that using websites is better is because of the scope of the settings, product price and enabled/disabled status for instance can only be set at the website level.  Also you will want to have one store view for each language you will support.  It's not that it's not advisable to have only one website, it's that one website won't allow you to do achieve the setup you describe.